# If I log onto someone else’s WiFi on my computer, would they be able to see my personal files?

Tags: wifi

If I was at someone’s house and I log into WiFi using their email and password, could they see what is on my computer?

Comment: short answer , NO ! but you do not need email, just a password to log in to WiFi

Comment: What kind of WiFi is this where you need email and password to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Normally they can not look inside your computer.

Just to make sure that is the case,

open system preferences > sharing

and make sure all items are disabled.

[image: sharing]